# Android Retrofit api call with space in parameter

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to make an API call using Retrofit 1.x:

```
@POST("/test?api-version=1.0")
void createMyStuff(
        @Header("X-Signature") String authorization,
        @Query(value="nickname") String nickname,
        @Query("language") String language,
        Callback<MyAPIResponse> cb);
```

**the issue** is :  nickname can have spaces in it. 
   So, before make the call,  if nickname is "John  Doe" (two spaces),  I replace space in it and send it like :  "John%20%20Doe" in the API call.

It fails with 400, Bad request.

The URL reported in the errorResponse object is :
    https://.com/foo/test?nickname=john%2520%2520doe&language=en-US

Notice that the %20 is replaced by  %2520

**What I investigated** : there isn't a definite answer. Someone on SO suggested in a thread to use FunName(value="apiname",encodeValue=true)
 But the encodeValue isn't resolving.

I also tried encoding with UTF-8 and it doesnt work. I am not sure about URL encoding since this is not really URL and will be only part of it.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you tried just passing it the string without being encoded in any way? So just pass it 'John Doe'.  %25 is the encoding for a '%' so it seems like it's taking 'john%20%20doe' and encoding it automatically thus giving you the 'john%2520%2520doe'

Comment: yes i did send with spaces. :-)  so have to resort to all these things.  That gave a 400 bad request as well.

Comment: Darn, worth a shot haha. Have you tried using @Path instead of @Query? So something like: 
`@POST("test?api-version=1.0&nickname={name}&language={lang}") 
void createMyStuff(
    @Header("X-Signature") String authorization, 
    @Path("name") String nickname, 
    @Path("lang") String language);`

Comment: didn't work  :   Declaration  :   @POST("/room?api-version=1.0&nickname={name}&language={lang}")
    void createRoomWithVoice(
            @Header("X-Signature") String authorization,
            @Path(value="name") String nickname,
            @Path(value="lang") String language,
            Callback<MyResponse> cb);     10-12 22:59:16.290 W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MyApi.createMySTuff: URL query string "api-version=1.0&nickname={name}&language={lang}​" must not have replace block.

Comment: Okay, what if you go back to the original way with Query params but you use `@EncodedQuery` this time and pass it a string you manually encoded. So basically exact same thing you were doing at first but swap out `@Query` for `@EncodedQuery`

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same problem

Comment: I m facing the same solution.. What will be the solution ? plz suggest.

Comment: @techtinkerer If you have solved problem, please add your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Retrofit2 Parameter names and values are URL encoded by default. You need to add `encoded = true` to change this behaviour.

```
void createMyStuff(
    @Header("X-Signature") String authorization,
    @Query(value="nickname", encoded = true) String nickname,
    @Query("language") String language,
    Callback<MyAPIResponse> cb);
```

Comment: So what you mean is that retrofit does the encoding for you? no need to use %20 with spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Actually %25 is encoding of % so when you put %20 it encodes % to %25 and 20 remains same. so you have to false its encoding in `@Query` parameter

```
@Query(value="nickname",encodeValue = false) String nickname
```

Now you can call it with %20 it will work fine

```
createMyStuff("Auth","John%20%20Doe","lang",new Callback<MyResponse>{....});
```